# Aligning Long Titles on CSS Responsive Grid

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

I have built a CSS responsive 3x3 grid. Each section contains an image and title. In some rows I have 1 long title and 2 short titles.

**CSS**

```
.third {
    width: 32%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 2% 2% 0;
}
.last {
    margin: 0 0 2% 0;
}
.entry-thumbnail {
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}
.entry-thumbnail img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

**HTML (First three sections)**

```
<section class="third">
    <div class="entry-thumbnail">
        <img src="http://bbc.in/1FG55RM" alt="Squirrel">
    </div>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <h1>Longer Title Here</h1>
    </header>
</section>

<section class="third">
    <div class="entry-thumbnail">
        <img src="http://bbc.in/1FG55RM" alt="Squirrel">
    </div>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <h1>Short Title</h1>
    </header>
</section>

<section class="third last">
    <div class="entry-thumbnail">
        <img src="http://bbc.in/1FG55RM" alt="Squirrel">
    </div>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <h1>Short Title</h1>
    </header>
</section>
```

The method I have used causes the grid to break when the screen size drops below 1436px: http://jsfiddle.net/2cp1dcjs.

The longer title in the first column pushes down the sections below.

Apart from setting a minimum height for each column, is there a better way to fix this? I'm using media queries to increase the section width to 48% once the screen size drops below 768px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replaced the `float:left` with `display:inline-block` in the class `.third` will fix your problem. I've updated the class `.third`. Check the updated fiddle sample

[Fiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/2cp1dcjs/3/)

Comment: Like Aru said, `display:inline-block` does the trick. But don't forget to add `vertical-align:top` to align the sections properly.

Comment: Excellent! I've never used this method before, thank you buddy.

Comment: Thanks all.. @ DriftingSteps, ofcourse, I've included vertical-align:top in the fiddle sample.. Thanks again..

Comment: Your solution has made me completely re-structure my grids and clean up my code. Great article here for anyone wanting to ditch floats: http://justifygrid.com.

Comment: @Squideyes,  I don't know whether "text-align:justify" will workout in your case, I guess it won't work for image gallery.. just give a try...

Comment: I've ditched the margins, so it works well. It's also meant I've removed an extra PHP counter which was adding the last class.